# VHDL syntax error near while

Tags: syntax, while-loop, vhdl

I wrote a VHDL code to find gcd of two numbers. However while compiling it's giving me the following error

> near "while": syntax error

The code is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity gcd is
port(a,b:in integer;
    c:out integer);
end gcd;

architecture gcd of gcd is
    function calc_gcd(a,b:integer) return integer is
    while a/=b loop
        if a>b then
            a:=a-b;
        else
            b:=a-b;
        end if;

    end loop;

    return m;
    end calc_gcd;
begin
process(a,b)
begin
gcd<=calc_gcd(a,b);
end process;
end gcd;
```

I checked the syntax. It seems correct. What's wrong?

PS : I use ModelSim Student edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `begin` statement for your function.

There's a couple of other errors.

You're trying to assign to an input argument (`a` and `b`).  Arguments to a function are copied onto the stack.  You could use a procedure, but it looks like you really want a local variable.

There is no declaration for `m`.  That's the one (a local variable).

Comment: Thanks a lot. There were a few more errors, but debugged.
One more thing, using variables is a must in functions?

Comment: I don't understand your 'One more thing', If you want to assign to a signal use a procedure.  There are four object classes in VHDL, constants, variables, signals and files.  Any of them can be arguments.  A function has a return value, it is an expression.  There are two types of procedures, sequential statements and concurrent statements. There's a requirement that only the first procedure assign signals for nested procedures.  You may need a reference text of some sort.